# how to run a html template on the project's base path 127.0.0.1:8000/ on python-django

Tags: python, django, path, django-urls, url-pattern

I am learning Python-Django
I want to run a html template on the project's very base site 127.0.0.1:8000/   I don't want to run it in 127.0.0.1:8000/polls or something like that. My myproject/urls.py file looks like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('?????')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls'))
]
```

I don't know what to include in place of '?????' to run a html template on 127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: `'polls.urls'` or just the view like you'll already be doing inside of that polls urls.py file

Answer (score 0):

You could just put the view you want to run on 127.0.0.1:8000/ directly.

> ```
> path('', views.your_view, name='name')
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a single page to render directly as a view, with no additional context, this is the easiest and best way to do this is using TemplateView from generic class-based views:

In your myproject/urls.py file replace this line path('', include('?????')), with below one:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='home'),
```

**OR**

If you want to use FBV's with some logic of to work before html is rendered or some context to be send as well then for this you have to include another urls.py file of an App and from that Apps urls.py you can make a route to a view in App which will render a html file.

**Main project urls.py file include your app.urls**:

```
path('', include('App.urls')),
```

**In App.urls.py file of app add a route to view:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

**In views.py you can add a view:**

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```